# создание потока

Tags: многопоточность

```
Дано создания потока, который подсчитывает некоторые операции:
Thread mThread = new Thread (Count)
mThread.Name = & quot; Поток & quot; + I.ToString ();
mThread.Start ();
Как приостановить выполнение потока на 3 секунды ?
a) mThread.Pause (3);
b) mThread.Sleep (3000)
c) Thread.Pause (3);
d) Thread.Sleep (3000)
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

d -> Thread.sleep(3000)

На будущее, лучше спрашивать такие вопросы на специализированных форумах ну или не показывать, что это тест, который вы сейчас проходите)

Comment: хорошо спасибо большое

Comment: А вообще вам решать, я лично не против на такие вопросы отвечать)
P.S. Поставите мне галочку ответа?)

Comment: можете мне еще помочь ?

Comment: Да, что там у вас?

Comment: ну если ван не сложно я б в телеграм кинул , если вы можете ))

Comment: скиньте свой телеграм

Comment: Кину, только с вас галочка ответа)))

Comment: Хорошо , поставлю

Comment: Только нужно подождать еще 7 минут

Comment: Все я поставил галочку )))

Comment: Ну так что поможешь ?